# Unable to install python3-gbinder

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.10, waydroid

```
   /h/user ~ sudo apt install python3-gbinder                                                                  03-Feb Thu 2022 17:02
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-gbinder : Depends: python3 (>= 3.9~) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   /h/user ~ python3 -V                                                                                        
Python 3.10.0
```

I need python3-gbinder for [waydroid](https://waydro.id/) (android emulator).

My python3 version 3.10.0 but it still doesn't work even when I try with root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of https://docs.waydro.id/usage/install-on-desktops one must use

```
export DISTRO="focal"
```

so

```
export DISTRO="focal" && \
sudo curl -# --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -Sf https://repo.waydro.id/waydroid.gpg --output /usr/share/keyrings/waydroid.gpg && \
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/waydroid.gpg] https://repo.waydro.id/ $DISTRO main" > ~/waydroid.list && \
sudo mv ~/waydroid.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/waydroid.list && \
sudo apt update
```

Credit goes to @y-shevchenko https://githubhot.com/repo/Anbox-halium/anbox-halium/issues/162

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cniw/7a0220ce8b75368f7f57aa422d3fea97/raw | bash
```

this should fix it