# Unable to install Waydroid on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.10, waydroid

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
python3-gbinder : Depends: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 is to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install python3-gbinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70971314/unable-to-install-python3-gbinder)